# How to access the class name inside the gem code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So I'm creating an `acts_as` kind of gem, and inside the gem I want a reference to the class that is including the gem, to define methods using its name, like for example

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_whatever
end
```

I want to define methods from the gem using that class's name

```
module LocalInstanceMethods
  define_method "other_#{something.name.underscore.pluralize}" do
  end
end
```

What am I supposed to put instead of this `something` so that I could create a method called `other_my_objects`?

**PS**: calling `self` references the module I'm inside which is something like

```
ActsAsWhatever::LocalInstanceMethods
```

And `self.class` is

```
Module
```

Comment: have you tried with self.class.name ?

Comment: yea, it returns the class name of the module, which is `Module`, I just added that to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured this out, @ChrisHeald's answer was close to correct, but a small detail was messing this up, here's what worked for me

```
module LocalInstanceMethods
  def self.included(klass)
    define_method "other_#{klass.name.underscore.pluralize}" do
    end
  end
end
```

The part `class < klass` was messing up the `self` and `klass` variables together, without it now `klass` is the actual Model that I want, so `klass.name` returns the string I wanted for my method to be defined.

Also took me a while to notice that this it was `def self.included` not an `included do` block, that part was messing up all my tests.

Answer (score 0):

In your module, you need an [included](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-included) implementation.

```
module LocalInstanceMethods
  def self.included(other)
    class << other
     define_method "other_#{self.class.name.underscore.pluralize}" do
       # ...
     end
    end
  end
end
```

This code will execute with `other` being the module that this module is mixed into when it is included on the most module. You then open that class and define method on *it* rather than defining the method on the module and mixing that method into the host module.

Comment: I think it's kinda working, but it gave me sort of a singleton class, `self.name` is nil, and `self.class` is class, self is `#<Class:Whatever(id: integer ...)` rather than just `Whatever(id: .. )`

Comment: Whoops, yeah, you want `self.class.name` in there.